# Angular 2 login/session data compared with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, angular, session

**TL;DR**
I realise this is very long winded, essentially I dont really see how tokens in local storage is secure nor how to generate them from a backend PHP login/register service like a basic website or even if thats a method to do so.

I am new to Angular 2, I have gotten a good feel for it now and can wrap my head around how it works but what I am currently faced with is dealing with login/session data and any sort of data that is user specific that must save (for instance, a cart of shopping items for an online store).

http://4dev.tech/2016/03/login-screen-and-authentication-with-angular2/ This tutorial goes over an extremely basic iteration but using dummy data I cant really mentally connect the dots on my own personal database integration and communication

I have already created a super basic login setup on my original HTML - PHP site that just queries a MySQL database with a username and encrypted password and returns a user ID as the result.

Then I would just have a global PHP file called that will tell the current page was logged in and if so, display x or y result and grab information from the logged in user like username or email.

What I'm trying to understand is how this is implimented in an Angular 2 system, can I use the same backend register/login PHP files my old javascript files called in my previous non-angular site and set a unique token from that; that I will then store locally with all the information of the logged in user?

Just in terms of security in my mind this feels odd, like you could manipulate the javascript client-side to tell it to have a valid token and then go about like you are logged in etc.
And how much information can be stored locally, do I 'ping' the database with an ID of sorts to retrieve information or is it in a token.

If its possible could someone supply a link or a super basic explaination/example of logging in/out from a MySQL Database with backend PHP and Angular? It would be easier if dummy data is not used, my personal server allows cross origin referencing so I am using that for my current testing with connections and data retrieval (I have backend PHP files that just print json data retrived from my database that I can easily show on my page)

An example of my current use with my own personal server and my Angular 2 project in Angular CLI looks like this;

**component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/retry';
import {GetDataService} from "../../../services/get-data.service";
import { AnimateAnimation} from "../../../animation/animate.animation";
import {Subscription} from "rxjs/Subscription";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-projects',
    templateUrl: './projects.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./projects.component.scss'],
    animations: [
        AnimateAnimation
    ]
})

export class ProjectsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    pageHeader:any = "ONLINE PORTFOLIO";
    showFooter:boolean = true;
    dataURL:string = 'https://callum.tech/php/json.php?table=projects';
    subscription:Subscription;
    data;

    constructor(private getData:GetDataService) {
        this.subscription = this.getData.getJSONData(this.dataURL).subscribe(
            data => this.data = data);
    }

    openSite(site:string) : void {
        window.open(site, "_blank");
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }
}
```

And to display data is like so;
**component.html**

```
<div [@fadeInOut] *ngIf="data;else other_content">
    <div class="row">
      <div *ngFor="let project of data" class="col-md-6">
        <div>
          <mat-card class="mat-elevation-z4">
            <mat-card-header>
              <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
              <mat-card-title>{{project.title}}</mat-card-title>
              <mat-card-subtitle>{{project.category}}</mat-card-subtitle>
              <div class="grow-empty"></div>
              <mat-card-content *ngIf="project.source">
                <button mat-raised-button (click)="openSite(project.source)">SOURCE</button>
              </mat-card-content>
            </mat-card-header>
            <img mat-card-image src="{{project.image}}" alt="{{project.title}}">
            <mat-card-content>
              <p>
                {{project.detail  | slice:0:200}}...
              </p><br>
              <mat-chip-list>
                <mat-chip color="accent" selected="true">{{project.tags}}</mat-chip>
              </mat-chip-list>
              </mat-card-content>
            <mat-card-actions>
              <button mat-raised-button>Information</button>
            </mat-card-actions>
          </mat-card>
        </div>
```

Just an example of how I go about using my live data to test in my project for my personal clarity

Comment: It doesn't matter if the front end thinks you're logged in as a super admin as long as the back end rejects all the requests where the token isn't valid or the user with that token isn't authorized to do what he/she's trying to do. The back end should be responsible for everything related to security. Any security checks in the front end is for user convinience only, never used as an actual security measure

Comment: So I use PHP to register a token that I return to the user, and return all the information related to the login that the front end might need like name, email, avatar etc?

Comment: How you transmit data is really just however you want to solve it. An easy way is to answer the login request with the logged in user object + a valid token for that user. But you can just as well return only the token and then request the profile data whenever you need it. Remember after logging in a user you want to pass the token with every request from the front end. I used to hook on to the requests so I didn't have to manually add the token everywhere in my code. That way you can also check for an invalid token and send the user to the log in screen if need be in that same place

Comment: So a few things; First off I will need to validate the token on every page before it attempts to load, and then all information I want to access in PHP i will send said valid token and retrieve my information is that correct? If you know, does PHP have an easy method of generating tokens or is that something I would need a library for or make my own function(s) to do so